# Com base em uma data, saber qual é a semana do ano

Tags: java

Considerando que 1 ano tem 12 meses e que cada mês tem 30 dias (mesmo fevereiro), e que 1 de janeiro pertence a semana 1 e 30 de dezembro a semana 52, criar um método que ao receber uma data (no caso um dia e um mês pois o ano não faz diferença ) indique qual é a semana. Caso alguém possa me ajudar, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo + ou - assim... Mas é só a lógica mesmo, porque não escrevi em uma IDE... n dá pra dizer que o código está certo ^^

```
//Aqui temos uma função que retornará uma variável do tipo inteiro
public int converterData(int _dia, int _mes){  

    //Aqui uma variável que vai armazenar o número de dias até aquela data
    int quantidadeDias = (((_mes - 1) * 30) + _dia);

    //Aqui dividimos por 7, ou seja, 7 dias na semana para saber o número de semanas
    int numeroSemana = (quantidadeDias / 7);

    //Aqui só retornamos a resposta
    return numeroSemana;
}
```

Para chamar a função você fará algo assim:

```
//Pronto, você já tem a resposta de qual semana vai ser no dia 05 de dezembro
int resposta = converterData(5,12);
```

A lógica é basicamente essa, mas nunca te retornará a resposta certa porque normalmente o ano começa com a primeira semana ainda no mês de Dezembro do ano passado...

Esse com certeza não é o melhor jeito... Acredito que o java deve ter alguma lib pra calendários

Dá uma olhada aqui: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20get%20week%20number

Muitas pessoas já tiveram a mesma dúvida, você pode achar algo ;)

Comment: Faz todo sentido, e é bem simples. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pode resolver usando a classe [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), que permite a manipulação de datas tanto para o calendário Gregoriano (o que usamos atualmente) quanto Juliano:

```
Date data = new Date(2015, 06 /* Mês */, 01/* Dia */);
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(data);
int semana = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println(semana);
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](http://ideone.com/2IdEe0).

Comment: Mas acho que dá diferença, não? A proposta é de que todos os meses do ano sejam de 30 dias.